# Unable to format Dollar Amount with Dollar sign and comma to simple number using Text to Column and Format Cells Option in Excel

Tags: excel

I was revisiting a Data Science Tutorial where the tutor is performing the data preparation phase. He formats date and Dollar Amount using the Text to column and then applying the respective format cells options, earlier when i did this both dates and dollar amount formatted well but due to some reasons i had to format my pc so i reinstalled everything, but now i am able to format only date column properly the dollar amount Column is not changing at all with the text to columns option in which it should get converted to number but it still remains text until i manually remove the dollar sign and comma using the find and replace option [original state of Date and Balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOfI4.png)[screenshot after "Text to Column" and "Format Cells" option was applied --date changed correctly to yyyy-mm-dd but Balance remained unchanged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Bi4.png)[screenshot when the balance changed when i removed the , and $ sign using find and replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJhnC.png).I wanted to know how to change the balance the same way as i changed the date format using "Text to Column" option and then applying Format cells. Do i have to reformat my pc ?Some related articles said that it has something to do with the system regional Locale Settings, but i did not touched it neither earlier(before format) or after format.

Comment: When you re-installed the operating system on your PC you did change everything - back to a default which may or may not have changed since you installed last. Go to the Control Panel > Clock/Language/Region > Change date, time & umber formats. Reviewing these settings, in fact, is indispensable part of the PC setup procedure, and be it only for knowing what the defaults in your PC are. You will understand your PC better - and feel free to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom formatting. Select all cells from column G, press `ctrl+1` > Custom, and as a formula use

```
$0,0.00
```

Answer (score -1):

it worked when i changed my regional setting to English(US) all thing is in Dollar that's why i guess it worked as the countries with different standard money it excel working in that regional would not recognize the money as Dollar as there some else money is used like Yen, or Euros etc.